# Netlify not showing images from cloudinary

Tags: reactjs, netlify, cloudinary

I have recently finished an ecommerce app - I have deployed backend to Heroku with Strapi and connected Cloudinary successfully. The frontend is a React app deployed to Netlify but images are still not showing.

I also tried to add the Netlify cloudinary plugin but still does not work, what else can be the problem? Is there another way of configuring frontend other than npm run build that I am not aware of?
Appreciate any input. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.